# Async timer in loop function without stopping main thread

Tags: c#

I created WPF form with a "Start" button, this button is "StartMacros" function.

When i click "Start" button i want to run a loop and open a firefox browser every 10 seconds, without stopping the MAIN thread, so i can create another "Pause" button or "Cancel" button

Right now everything is working but there is no delay in the loop, how can i create it? the "await Task.Delay((10000));" is not creating the delay..

```
    public void StartMacros(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AsyncTimerLoop();
    }

    public async void AsyncTimerLoop()
    {
        for (int profileNumber = 1; profileNumber <= 10; profileNumber++)
        {
            OpenBrowser(profileNumber);
            await Task.Delay((10000));
        }
    }
    public void OpenBrowser(int profileNumber)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "-P " + profileNumber + " -no-remote imacros://run/?m=\"" + ImacroFilePath + "\"");
    }
```

Comment: You have to run it asynchronously. Task.Run(() => AsyncTimerLoop()); Also you should return Task or Task<T> with async methods.

Comment: `async void` is almost always a bad idea. Also, you're not awaiting the call to `AsyncTimerLoop`

Comment: FCin this delay won't stop the main thread?

Comment: @Valoda It won't stop main thread. You want to delay task or main thread? Currently with `Task.Run()` you will delay task, which I assume is what you want?

Comment: Make your button click event handler `public async void StartMacros`, then call your method like this `await AsyncTimerLoop();`, then change your `AsyncTimerLoop()` method signature to return `Task` instead of `void`, and use `await Task.Delay((10000)).ConfigureAwait(false);` (adding `ConfigureAwait(false)`), unless you wanted to do GUI operations inside after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with just one method:

```
private async void StartMacros(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int profileNumber = 1; profileNumber <= 10; profileNumber++)
    {
        OpenBrowser(profileNumber);
        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
}
```

Note, I have added the `async` keyword to the method.

What's going on here is subtle.  The reason your code didn't work as expected was because your `StartMacros` was calling your `AsyncTimerLoop` method *synchronously*.  It calls the method which then loops a bunch of times really fast on the main thread.  Within each loop iteration, it calls your `OpenBrowser` (still on the main thread) and then awaits a call to `Task.Delay` (which actually returns an awaitable `Task`, but your code doesn't do anything with that -- it just throws them away).  Since you called it with the `await` keyword, it does that on another thread -- one thread for each loop iteration -- and just continues looping on the main thread, calling `OpenBrowser` in each loop, until it finishes the loop and exits the function; all this happens very rapidly.  The calls to `Task.Delay` don't do anything except delay for ten seconds on another thread and then exit.  They're basically useless.

Now, you could do this:

```
private async void StartMacros(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await AsyncTimerLoop();
}

public async Task AsyncTimerLoop()
{
    for (int profileNumber = 1; profileNumber <= 10; profileNumber++)
    {
        OpenBrowser(profileNumber);
        await Task.Delay((10000));
    }
}
```

Notice here that I've added the `async` keyword to `StartMacros` just like in my code above, and I'm also *awaiting* the call to `AsyncTimerLoop`.  In order to do that, I had to change the return type of `AsyncTimerLoop` to `Task`, making it *awaitable*.  Now when you run the code, it awaits the whole call to `AsyncTimerLoop` on a separate thread, immediately returning control to to `StartMacros` which exits right away so the application event loop can resume, leaving the application responsive.  Meanwhile, the whole `AsyncTimerLoop` task is running on a separate, *single* thread, waiting ten seconds during each loop iteration and therefore waiting ten seconds between each call to `OpenBrowser`.

My code is similar to this modified version of yours, it's just more concise.

Comment: It's cleaner than having a pointless `AsyncTimerLoop` method, in this scenario.

Comment: @Valoda -- You're welcome.  See my update for an explanation of what's going on.

Comment: @rory.ap I don't think the above explanation is quite accurate. `await Task.Delay((10000)).ContinueWith((arg) => OpenBrowser(profileNumber));` should be the correct way of doing it. However, as OP originally requested, Cancellation has not been considered here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, use

```
 var task = Task.Run(() => OpenBrowser(profileNumber));
    if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000)))
    {
       return task.Result;   
    }
```

Add System.Threading.Tasks namespace to your code to access Task Parallel Library.

```
 using System.Threading.Tasks;


 public void StartMacros(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    AsyncTimerLoop();
 }

public async void AsyncTimerLoop()
{
    for (int profileNumber = 1; profileNumber <= 10; profileNumber++)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => OpenBrowser(profileNumber));
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000)))
        {
          return task.Result;   
        } 
    }
}
public void OpenBrowser(int profileNumber)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "-P " + profileNumber + " -no-remote imacros://run/?m=\"" + ImacroFilePath + "\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a timer be easier?

```
var timer = new Timer(o => Console.WriteLine("{0} Tick", DateTime.Now), null, 0, 6000);
```